# Dataset manipulation

Tags: r

I have a large dataset below is a small portion:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7  V8 V9 V10
1:  174 174  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
2:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
3:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
4:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
5:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
6:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
7:  174  NA  NA 174  NA 174 NA 174 NA  NA
8:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
9:  174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
10: 174  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA  NA
```

I want to place a '1' wherever there is a '174' and output this into one column.  I am trying to change the format so that I can run a logistic regression on my data. The final output should look like:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1
10: 1
```

Comment: do you want to change *all* 174 in the dataset to 1 and output the first column, change *only* the first column to 1 where it equals 174 and output the whole column (including NA), or output a *column* of 1's equal to the total number of replacements in the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `[` subsetting operator.

```
# Create some example data
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix( c(rep(174,5),rep(NA,20)) ,nrow=5)
m[ sample(5:25,3) ] <- 174
m
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  174   NA  174   NA   NA
#[2,]  174   NA  174   NA   NA
#[3,]  174   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]  174   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]  174   NA   NA  174   NA


# Compare values in matrix to '174' and change to '1' if condition is TRUE
m[ m == 174 ] <- 1
m
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1   NA    1   NA   NA
#[2,]    1   NA    1   NA   NA
#[3,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]    1   NA   NA    1   NA
```

If you only want the replacement to occur in the first column, you could use `which` to logically compare the values from the first *column* to 174 and change those that are 174:

```
m[ which( m[1:nrow(m)] == 174 ) ] <- 1
m
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1   NA  174   NA   NA
#[2,]    1   NA  174   NA   NA
#[3,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]    1   NA   NA  174   NA

m[,1]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

In the example I am working with matrices and it outputs a vector. You can do much the same thing with data.frames (but be careful, under the hood they are very different from matrices, as long as you have numeric data this will be *safe*);

```
df <- data.frame(m)
df[,1]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: I think Brianna wanted this to only happen in column 1.

Comment: @DWin hmm, re-reading it the question does seem a little ambiguous.

Comment: I wanted to have just one column at the end, if that makes sense?

Comment: @BriannaMarie so the first column in your original dataset? OR one column that is all the 174's in your original data?

Comment: If you need it to *look* like a column then try `data.frame( df[,1] )` or `data.frame( m[,1] )`

Comment: I have a vector now here is my Code: